# How does tcl exec work exactly?

Tags: exec, tcl

I am automating some work that requires calling `tcpdump -nn -tt -r` on some .pcap files.

To do this I"m using the following tcl code:

```
set magic_dir "results/pcap/";
set magic_filename "data"
set magic_node_count 16
set magic_command "tcpdump"

for {set i 0} {$i <= $magic_node_count} {incr i} \
  {
    set filename "${magic_dir}${magic_filename}-${i}-0.pcap"
    if {[file exists $filename]} \
      {
        set dest_dir "${magic_dir}\.\./tmp/tmp_${i}"
        exec ${magic_command} -nn -tt -r ${filename} > ${dest_dir}
      } \
  }
```

This works (the first file gets converted) but tcl reports an error in that line.
The same thing happens later on in the script when I attempt to use grep. I avoid this by using `catch` but I would like to know how to properly use this command.

Comment: Lots of useful discussion at http://wiki.tcl.tk/exec

Comment: So grep and tcpdump are writing to stderr and tcl thinks it's an error? I am not sure I understand what is the general lesson with exec but my script appears to be working perfectly with catch at this time.

Comment: If you don't consider the command outputting to stderr a problem, use `exec -ignorestderr` -- http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/exec.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Tcl's `exec` generates an error if *either*

1. The command has a non-zero exit code, or
2. The command produces output on its standard error channel.

Of these two, you pretty much have to handle the first by using `catch` (or `try`/`trap` in Tcl 8.6) since that's almost always a genuine error. (Or not; `grep` is a classic problem.) But with standard error processing, you've got more options (assuming you're [using 8.5](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/exec.htm)).

For example, you can redirect to the terminal:

```
exec ${magic_command} -nn -tt -r ${filename} > ${dest_dir} 2>/dev/tty
```

or to the normal standard error channel:

```
exec ${magic_command} -nn -tt -r ${filename} > ${dest_dir} 2>@stderr
```

or you can just tell Tcl to throw it away:

```
exec -ignorestderr ${magic_command} -nn -tt -r ${filename} > ${dest_dir}
```

or even combine it into the standard output:

```
exec ${magic_command} -nn -tt -r ${filename} > ${dest_dir} 2>@1
```

You can get more exotic by introducing extra pipelines (e.g., with 8.6's `chan pipe` or through trickiness with an external `cat -u`) but that starts to get *really* complicated fast. Since you're automating tcpdump, you may well be best off just combining everything into one and working with that. Or using considerably-greater power and sophistication of the Expect package.

Comment: Is there any way to get exec to work with grep when you look for a string with spaces? I thought it would be straightforward but it has been eluding me for the past hours. I am trying to do something like exec grep -orI '> 10.1.1.1.160' but it seems to insist that 10.1... is a directory. If I try to escape the space '>\ 10.1.1.1.160' it just halts.